# gdb script, assign functions' return value in user variable

Tags: gdb

I would like to assign the "info sharedlibrary" value to a variable in user define function.

Such as,

```
define customFunction

    set $i = info sharedlibrary

end
```

But it seems impossible in gdb
And also i cannot use python script too...

Is there any way to do this??

Thank you

ps. I trying to do this because i want to print only selected library's instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention *why* you can't use a Python function.  That's by far the simplest way to program gdb.

However, if you really must do it, and really must avoid Python, there is a way.  It's gross!  But it does work.  It's like this:

- Use the various `set logging` commands to redirect output to a temporary file.
- Invoke the command you want.
- Use `set logging` again to disable logging.
- Use the `shell` command to run `sed` or `perl` or what-have-you on this temporary file to turn it into a sequence of gdb commands, say commands to set a variable, or commands to print exactly the output you want.
- `source` the resulting file

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot. It's really helpful to me.
And the reason that I cannot use Python is because i trying to use gdb in my Android devices.